# Creating an app to pull in announcements via JSON

Tags: javascript

I have the code to pull in my data, but I'm new to Sharepoint and need some help. Where can I find some resources to figure out how to get started. I'm used to building stand-alone sites with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, but I haven't the slightest idea as to how to get started with doing the same type of stuff in this environment.

Here's my data: http://jsfiddle.net/3pb5vv1j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint is a content management platform. I comes with lot of features out of the box and using that you can create applications with no code at all.

There will be situations you require to customize, in those cases you have following options

1. Using SharePoint designer
2. Using Visual Studio

Following are different technologies you can use

1. Server Side object Model
2. Web Services
3. REST End Points
4. Client Side Object Model
5. JavaScript Object Model

https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Get-started-with-SharePoint-2013-909ec2f0-05c8-4e92-8ad3-3f8b0b6cf261?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN